# System.Management.Automation error access denied

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

System.Management.Automation class I use the c # PowerShell exchange programs that access the server, increase the tasks of e-mail accounts, a program error access denied;

```
<pre><code>
 PSCredential credentials = new PSCredential(UserName, ssRunasPassword);
              //ExchangeUri=ExUri
                WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(ExchangeUri, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", credentials);
                connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;

                Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
                runspace.Open();
</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.. an access denied error is pretty straightforward. I modified your code a little bit:

```
        string username = @"domain\username";
        string password = "pass";
        SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password)
        {
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }
        securePassword.MakeReadOnly();

        PSCredential credentials = new PSCredential(username, securePassword);
        //ExchangeUri=ExUri
        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(ExUri), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", credentials);
        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;

        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
        runspace.Open();
```

If this does not work, you can try establishing a remote session through [PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession) to see if you actually have access to the server.

Comment: hi. Thank you for your answer, but seem to have not special code changes, just added the  username and password  of code that I didn't post, the deny access tips  is I built the server problems